# What does it mean for columns to lie in the same plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system of equations:

$$
u + v + w = b_1 \\
2u + 3w = b_2 \\
3u + v + 4w = b_3 \\
$$

In section 1 of Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra and its Applications, there's the following figure (Figure 1.6):

[image]

What does it mean for columns to be inside a plane? I know that the columns would be the coefficient vectors for $u, v, w$, or $[1,2,3], [1,0,1], [1,3,4]$. All of these vectors have the same first value of $1$, so I suppose they do reside in the same plane. Therefore, does the figure imply that it is a slice of 3-dimensional space where the first dimension is fixed at 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He means a plane *through the origin*. That’s what the dot at the intersection of the rays representing the vectors in the figure is supposed to convey. It’s certain that not just any plane is meant, since *every* set of three points is coplanar.

Comment: In other words, he is simply indicating that there are three vectors (or points) that are coplanar to a plane through the origin (since they could be a coplanar to a plane that does not go through the origin). The use of the word _columns_ was confusing to me here.

Comment: @190290000RubleMan Right. “Columns” here is short for “columns of the matrix treated as vectors in their own right.”

Answer (score 1):

> Columns lying in a plane

means:

If you make a matrix out of the LHS of the system of equations and consider the columns of the matrix as vectors, then if three or more columns are dependent then the corresponding vectors will lie in the same plane determined by any $2$ of the dependent vectors. (Remember only 2 vectors are required to determine a plane).

Answer (score 0):

If you can express one of the vectors as a linear combination of the other two, then all three vectors lie in a common plane, and points off that plane cannot be expressed by linear combinations of the vectors. Effectively, you have only two independent vectors, not three.

However - unless the value is zero - it doesn't typically mean that one of the coordinates is fixed at a certain value. In your example, the vectors can be shown to be on the same plane because $3u-v=2w$. Other vectors on the same plane can be found by combinations of the given vectors - eg. $[0,2,2]$